# WebView When wrong url put it give warning

Tags: webview, react-native

I am using the webview when i give the wrong url it give the warnig i want to remove this warnig and only show page not found in react native 
My Code is

```
<WebView style={{flex:1,margin:20}}
  ref={WebView_Ref}
  source={{uri: 'https://www.gooef.com'}}
/>
```

I want for above url webview show only page not found not give the warnig Err_connection_refused url wrong

Answer (score 0):

use renderError props.

```
const errorPage = () =>{
  return (
    <Text>{'page not found '}</Text>
  )
}


//..
<WebView 
  renderError={errorPage}
  style={{flex:1,margin:20}}
  ref={WebView_Ref}
  source={{uri: 'https://www.gooef.com'}}
/>
```

Comment: sir with this it show page not found but this is already show by webview...but my problem is that it show the warnig encountered the error loading ...err_name_not resolved url="https//ww.fdfdfd.com,"target:20

Comment: sir is there any method to remove this warnig..plz help me i will thankful to u

Comment: it also show an error cangoforward={false} cangoback={false}

Comment: if i disable warning then it not show the page not found page because it move to next page for warning

Comment: Wncounterd an error loading page {canGoForward:false,code:-2,"canGoback":false,description:net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED,"LOADING:false,title","Google,"url":https://www.fffdfffd.com/","target":20}

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the warning yellow box?
if yes, do this: add 
console.disableYellowBox = true;
in YourFile.js

Comment: when url wrong in webview then it show a page page not found as in our browser....But in my case it show a little time page not found then move toward warning and the pagenot found page hide.....when i disable the warning then it show the white screen

Comment: sir if u not understand plz try to create one webview and give the wrong url and check if u disable warnig then it show nothing

Comment: sir plz give the solution....when user enter wrong url then what is the output i demand only this output

Comment: Hi, i do try to reproduce the scenario, however mine work just fine without the situation you mentioned.

Comment: sir when u give the wrong url then what is the output...In my case warnig come for wrong url...And for a little bit moment a window show pagenot found after that moves toward warning and when i disable warnig it not show the pagenotfound page

Comment: When I give a false url, the webview will direct to the page not found page. A yellow warning box is appeared at the bottom. When i disable the warning, everything work fine.

Comment: at which place you disable warning i disable at render

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144903/discussion-between-kimhau-and-farrukh).